# Where do I put my environment variables for API credentials?

Tags: python, api, spotify, credentials

I'm trying to work with the Spotify API and it needs client credentials. I've integrated spotipy and it works fine when I don't need to request user info (i.e. just downloading track names from an artist) but I wish to access audio features.

In what file/script and how do I include credentials?

This is what they say in the oauth2.py file:

```
    You can either provid a client_id and client_secret to the
    constructor or set SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID and SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET
    environment variables
```

https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/audio_features.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start [here - Authorized Requests](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorized-requests).  Then you can simply use this example:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)
if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

To get things started and then grab what you need.

See [this page](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for full documentation. And [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-spotipy.oauth2) for details using the **SpotifyClientCredentials**.